# detox ReferenceError: before is not defined

Tags: javascript, react-native, e2e-testing, detox

I am using the Detox Test tool, and I am having difficulties.

I only installed Detox, I only ran the basic code for the ios test, and I get the following error:

Please help me.

Just iOS

**Error Log**

```
$ detox test --configuration ios.sim.debug --debug-synchronization --take-screenshots all --record-videos nonex --record-logs all
node_modules/.bin/jest e2e --config=e2e/config.json --maxWorkers=1 --testNamePattern='^((?!:android:).)*$'
 FAIL  e2e/firstTest.spec.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: before is not defined

      3 | const adapter = require('detox/runners/mocha/adapter');
      4 | 
    > 5 | before(async () => {
        | ^
      6 |   await detox.init(config);
      7 | });
      8 | 

      at Object.<anonymous> (init.js:5:1)
```

**package.json**

```
"script":{
   "e2e:ios": "detox test --configuration ios.sim.debug --debug-synchronization --take-screenshots all --record-videos nonex --record-logs all",
   "e2e:android": "detox test --configuration android.emu.debug --loglevel verbose --take-screenshots all --record-videos none --record-logs all"
        },
   dependencies": {
        "detox": "^8.0.0",
        "jest": "^23.1.0",
        "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    },
    "detox": {
        "configurations": {
          "ios.sim.debug": {
            "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/{app_name[enter image description here][1]}.app",
            "build": "xcodebuild -workspace ios/{workspace_Name}.xcworkspace -scheme {scheme_name} Dev -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build",
            "type": "ios.simulator",
            "name": "iPhone 7"
          },
          "android.emu.debug": {
            "binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/dev/debug/{apk_name}.apk",
            "build": "react-native run-android --variant=devDebug --appId com.noahclient.dev",
            "type": "android.emulator",
            "name": "Nexus_5X_API_26"
          }
        },
        "test-runner": "jest"
      }
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looks like you are trying to run a mocha test on the jest runner. As your init.js is setup for mocha but the test runner that you are using is jest. This is confirmed by the  error message `node_modules/.bin/jest e2e...` that you are getting.

You should pick either one, jest or mocha and use it. Rather than trying to use both.

#Jest
If you are using **jest** your init.js should look like this:

```
const detox = require('detox');
const config = require('../package.json').detox;
const adapter = require('detox/runners/jest/adapter');

jest.setTimeout(120000);
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(adapter);

beforeAll(async () => {
  await detox.init(config);
});

beforeEach(async () => {
  await adapter.beforeEach();
});

afterAll(async () => {
  await adapter.afterAll();
  await detox.cleanup();
});
```

and you should add `"test-runner": "jest"` to the detox object in your package.json.

You should also have a `config.json` file in the same location as the `init.js` containing:

```
{
  "setupFilesAfterEnv" : ["./init.js"]
}
```

#Mocha
If you are using **mocha** then your init.js should look like this:

```
const detox = require('detox');
const config = require('../package.json').detox;
const adapter = require('detox/runners/mocha/adapter');

before(async () => {
  await detox.init(config);
});

beforeEach(async function () {
  await adapter.beforeEach(this);
});

afterEach(async function () {
  await adapter.afterEach(this);
});

after(async () => {
  await detox.cleanup();
});
```

and you should remove the `"test-runner": "jest"` from the detox object in your package.json as it is not required.

Instead of a `config.json` file you should have a `mocha.opts` file beside your `init.js` and it should have something similar to:

```
--recursive
--timeout 120000
--bail
```

#Next steps

1. Choose the test runner that you are wanting to run; either **jest** or
   **mocha**.
2. Make sure you have the correct init.js file for the test runner.
3. If using **jest** have a config.json file and add the test-runner to the detox object in the package.json.
4. If using **mocha** have a mocha.opts file. No need to specify a test-runner in the detox object in the package.json.

You can see the setup instructions here: https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/docs/Introduction.GettingStarted.md#step-3-create-your-first-test

If you are still having issues let me know.

Comment: I did not know it was an option.
Thank you. : )